# Python, can I format user input before a while statement checks for a condition to happen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, type-conversion, number-formatting

This is kind of a stupid question but:

I need to get a float that represents my user's portfolio, so I need to check for the input to be a number and if it contains a comma I want to change it with a dot.

I've got this piece of code:

```
portfolio_size = input('Insert portfolio size:')
portfolio_size = portfolio_size.replace(",", ".")

while not(portfolio_size.isnumeric()):
    print("\nInput Wrong \nPlease try again!")
    portfolio_size = input('Insert portfolio size:').replace(",",".") #This doesn't work
val = float(portfolio_size)
print(val)
```

I thought of using a ***while not*** statement to create a loop but I'm stuck on how to use the **replace(",",".")** method in this case since the "while not" doesn't accept any kind of string and if I try to input something like "33,18" it will just prompt me for an input again

Is there a workaround for that or a more elegant way to get the same result?

Comment: You can just do `portfolio_size = int(portfolio_size)` before the loop to change it to an int

Comment: I thought of that, but I need the value to be a float since it represents the amount of money the users owns. Also the first two strings of codes are just a first input prompt, I thought my while loop would start only if the user made a mistake

Comment: My mistake. One sec, I'll write a quick example of what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert to a float and catch the exception if the conversion doesn't work:

```
portfolio_size = ''
valid = False

while not valid:
    portfolio_size = input('Insert portfolio size:')

    try:
        portfolio_size = float(portfolio_size.replace(",", "."))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nInput Wrong \nPlease try again!")
        continue

    valid = True

print(portfolio_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

`isnumeric` function doesn't check if it is `float` (It only works with `int`)

Try This:

```py
portfolio_size = input('Insert portfolio size:')
portfolio_size = portfolio_size.replace(",", ".")

while True:
    if portfolio_size.isnumeric():
        break
    
    try:
        float(portfolio_size)
    except ValueError:
        print("\nInput Wrong \nPlease try again!")
        portfolio_size = input('Insert portfolio size:').replace(",",".") #This doesn't work
        continue
    
    break
    
val = float(portfolio_size)
print(val)
```

It doesn't look like pythonic code, but I hope it would help you

Comment: The `isnumeric` isn't doing anything there, it will always return false if the user has typed a float. You're also doing two conversions to float when one appropriately-placed one will be enough.

Comment: This actually worked, thank you very much. Btw I'd like to point out that the isnumeric() function seemed to also work with floats, so I'll read a bit more about it but this is a smart solution. Nice coding my friend! :)